# Accessing subclass variables via interface

Tags: java, interface

I have the following Java code:

```
public interface Person {
    int eat (String food);
    int sleep (int time);
    boolean doStuff (person partner);
}

public class Citizen implements Person {
    private int passion;
    private int morality;
    private String party;
    public citizen () {
        passion = 0;
        morality = 100;
        party = "Democrat";
    }
    public boolean doStuff (person partner) {
        passion += 10;
        morality -= 10;
        return true;
    }
    ... rest of implementation methods
}
```

And in the main method, I have these lines:

```
 Person Jon = new Citizen();
 System.out.println(Jon.party);
```

The second line fails. I am unable to access a subclass's variables via an interface. Why is this? We can do this just fine with methods:

```
 Person Jon = new Citizen();
 Person Romney = new Citizen();
 System.out.println(Jon.doStuff(Romney));
```

The above three lines work just fine - in other words, the methods of the interface are dynamic. Why is it not the same with variables, and is there a way around this?

Comment: Try to read about java conventions.. Classes and Interfaces are capital and variables are not. It is easier to read the code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to capitalize the names. Will do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*party* is a private instance attribute, you need to write a public getter to access it. 
Also, you should be *implementing* your interface instead of *extending* it.

And I recommend starting your class and interface names with a capital letter, this is a general naming convention in Java. The variables, on the other hand, should not start with a capital letter. I recommend you to read the [Code Convention for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

```
public class Citizen implements Person {
     public String getParty() {
         return party;
     }    
}
```

Comment: So if party was static, I could access it without the public getter?

Comment: You have to differentiate between the access level modifiers (public, private, protected) and whether an attribute is an instance or class attribute.

If your instance attribute party was public you would have been able to access it directly: jon.party. If it was static, you would have been able to access it through your class: Jon.party. Also in that case its state would have been the same for all the instances of this class, which is not something you want.

Bottom line, add a public getter for each private attribute that you need an access to.